# Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I'm trying to run the following code in Eclipse IDE (Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)) on Linux (JDK home: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`) with Kotlin plugins installed (Enhanced Kotlin for Eclipse [latest] + Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.24 [latest]):

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    /** Synchronous code example */
    println("Weather forecast")
    println("Sunny")
    
    println("\n\n--------------------------\n\n")
    
    /** With a delay */
    println("Weather forecast")
    //delay(1000)
    println("Sunny")
}
```

with `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    // For build.gradle (Groovy DSL)
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.9.21"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC2")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

however, trying to run Main.kt I'm getting the following exception:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainKt
```

Buildship version:

```
  Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle    3.1.9.v20240116-1515    org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship
```

I'm using Gradle version 8.6-rc-4 as **Specific Gradle version** configuration in Gradle panel under Window > Preferences.

Tree directory structure is the following:

```
.
├── bin
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── Main.kt
```

Any hints on how to proceed further?

Comment: I ended up downloading Intellij IDEA Community edition. Discarded Eclipse.